# Can I cover up a doorbell transformer?

Tags: transformer, doorbell, cover

The doorbell transformer is located on the opposite wall from my doorbell.  It is attached to a garage wall, uncovered.  It is ugly.  My question is: Can I cover it?

Comment: A photo would help, but there is no reason not to.

Comment: As long as the cover doesn't trap heat, sure, why not

Comment: If you have a smart (power-hungry) doorbell, the transformer might need ventilation, but even then, probably not. They are just chunks of iron and copper, and they typically don't work very hard, so the temp when covered should not be a problem. Cover it up for an hour or two and check the temp of the case; if it's too hot to touch, you might want to come up with a more open covering, or add vent holes/slots to it.

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can.  I covered this one with a replacement doorbell cover.

[image: Before][image: After]

The doorbell cover was intended to slip over an existing doorbell housing, but a leftover angle bracket from an IKEA bookcase worked just as well.